# Can't get bootstrap-modal.js to work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get bootstrap-modal.js to work in Rails but can't figure it out. At this point, I'm just trying to get the event to fire when I click the button as in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/xt4aQ/16/

using the exact same code in Rails nothing's happening when I click.

I have this  html set up in a view

```
<h3>Demo</h3>
          <!-- sample modal content -->
          <div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
              <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>One fine body…</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn primary">Primary</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn secondary">Secondary</a>
            </div>
          </div>

<button data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn danger">Launch Modal</button>
```

And `bootstrap-modal.js` copied into the javascripts folder in the assets pipeline

In Rails, [image]

But nothing's happening when I click launch in my rails application

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xt4aQ/21/

Comment: still didn't work, i think it has something to do with how the code's included in my rails app. I click on the button in Firebug and nothing happens. no error message

Comment: = javascript_include_tag "application"  wasn't in layout. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

wasn't in the application layout so bootstrap-modal.js also wasn't included.  problem now solved.